# How to get the sed command to only search for full words?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm fairly new to Linux and recently started experimenting with the command line. I decided to make a file and called it 'hi.txt'. The contents of the document was:

```
This is hi.txt.
hi 
hi
hi
```

I used the command `sed -i 's/hi/hotel/g' hi.txt` in hopes of making all the 'hi's in the document change to hotel. This was the output:

```
Thotels is hotel.txt
hotel
hotel
hotel
```

As you can see, the 'hi' is the word 'This' also got changed. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s///` command expects the "search" parameter to be a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Most versions of `sed` should support the `\b` match, which is a zero-width match at a word-nonword or a word-edge boundary. "Word" in this case is defined as a character that is either a letter, digit, or underscore (`_`). For example, if we assume the string `c++` is on a line by itself in your file, `\b` would match at the following positions:

1. Immediately before the `c`.
2. Between the `c` and the first `+`.
3. Immediately after the last `+`.

The following command should give you the desired results:

```
sed -i 's/\bhi\b/hotel/g' hi.txt
```

The word `this` will fail to match because the `h` is preceded by a word character (`t`), and the `i` is followed by a word character (`s`). However, the string `This is hi.txt` will match on the second instance of `hi`, because the surrounding space and `.` are both non-word characters.

Comment: `\b` is a GNU extension to sed (probably borrowed from `perl`), which is not a problem here because the OP said he was running Linux (so he will have GNU sed by default).  For proof of this, try running your sed script with `--posix` to disable all GNU extensions, and it will fail to change 'hi' to 'hotel' - without the GNU extensions it is searching for 'bhib'

Comment: @cas Good point. An alternative would be to use `\<` and `\>`, which match the beginning and end of a word, respectively. While not POSIX nor completely portable, they are supported on [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE) and [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5175/regexp-5.html), as well as by BusyBox `sed` (though [this page](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Regex) suggests they may be buggy on FreeBSD and BusyBox). In any event, OP can likely use `\b` on Linux, as you noted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -e 's/\([^[:alnum:]_.-]\)hi\([^[:alnum:]_.-]\)/\1hotel\2/g' -e 's/^hi$/hotel/' <file
This is hi.txt.
hotel
hotel
hotel
```